# I keep getting - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

Beginner programmer here so I apologize if I'm going to put an all out code block, but regarding the proble, I'm trying to call a method from another package and use it on my main package, but somehow the error (in the title) keeps popping up and saying that the method is null. I'm kind of at a loss since I've tried a bunch of different initializations that I know  and it's still popping up. Ty in advance to those who will make me understand. :]

Main Code:

```
package HMS_GUI;

import HMS_Elements.Login;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class HMS_Main {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login window = new Login();
                    window.f1.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public HMS_Main() {
        Login login = new Login();
        login.ini();
    }
}
```

Package code to be used in Main:

```
package HMS_Elements;

import HMS_GUI.HMS_Main;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Login extends HMS_Main {
    
    public JFrame f1;
    public JTextField txtUn;
    private JPasswordField txtPw;
    
    public void ini() {
        
        f1.setResizable(false);
        f1.setTitle("Electro Inc.");
        f1.setBounds(100, 100, 629, 361);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("LOGIN");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txtUn.getText();
                char[] pass = txtPw.getPassword();
                char[] pw = {'2', '0', '2', '3'};
                Arrays.equals(pw,pass);
    }
});
        
    }
}
```

Results in the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at HMS_GUI.HMS_Main.<init>(HMS_Main.java:28)
    at HMS_Elements.Login.<init>(Login.java:17)
        ...

infinitely on the same lines...
```

Comment: `Login` extends `HMS_Main`, so `new Login()` implicitly calls  the `public HMS_Main()` constructor. And `HMS_Main()` does another `new Login()`, which again implicitly calls  the `public HMS_Main()` constructor. And so on.